# The opposite of Transitivity (relations, set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

A relation $R$ is called 'transitive' when it upholds

$$ xRy ~\text{ and }~ yRz \implies xRz. $$

Is there a name for a relation that upholds the somewhat opposite property:

$$ xRz \implies \exists y ~\text{ such that }~ xRy \text{ and } yRz \enspace ? $$

Comment: If $R$ is reflexive, then $x=y$ satisfies the conditions.  Namely, if $xRz$ is true, then $xRx$ and $xRz$ are true.  Perhaps you want $y\not=x,z$.

Comment: Adding some background: I'm thinking about translation. Due to ambiguity it is not transitive, but the nameless property above seems to be correct --  if x translates to z (in languages L1 and L3), there should be an instance y in (any) language L2 such that x translates to y and y translates to z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Long Answer:** So, I wouldn't exactly call this the opposite of the transitivity relation. Surely, you can have both properties hold.  If I were going to give this property a name, one might call it a *density* property. If $R$ is the ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$, this is property says that is $a < b$ then $\exists c$ such that $a < c < b$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It feels like it should be called that. Do you know if it's actually canon though?

Comment: No idea, but I have seen it called that and I've never seen it called anything else, so . . . at least it's some kind of artillery?